# How can I send Android notifications from my Unity game?

Tags: unity, c#, android

I'm want to send local notification on Android with Unity3D but I don't know how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: When should these notifications be sent? What kind of content or action do they need to support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an easy way to implement it, there's this free asset:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/simple-android-notifications-free-68626

If you want to make it yourself (if you for some reason need a more complex system), you can read this discussion:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/push-notifications-on-unity-android.126528/

In case the forum or the linked post shuts down, here's a general overview of the information contained within:

- There is no native Unity support for it.
- It's really difficult to build it yourself, so it is recommended you don't because there are plugins that people have already made for it.
- If you want to do it yourself, you'll have to go into the Android documentations and figure out how to communicate to it from within Unity.

Then there are a few people trying to sell their own solutions on the asset store.

So **tl;dr:** *Use the free assets, it saves you time, money and frustration.*

Good luck!